# How do you get the UTC of a datetime Field?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL 5 and I am trying to convert a datetime field to a UTC_TIMESTAMP. Here is what I have but it's not working and not sure if I could even do this. But could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks

I have tried this:

```
SELECT
UTC_TIMESTAMP(start),
c.login_datetime as `start`
FROM
tbl_employees_login AS c
```

And This...

```
SELECT
UTC_TIMESTAMP(c.login_datetime) as `start`
FROM
tbl_employees_login AS c
```

And neither works!!

Comment: `DATETIME` fields are stored without any timezone information, so it is (somewhat) meaningless to convert them to a UTC timestamp (MySQL will assume it is in the then current session's [`time_zone`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_time_zone)): they are effectively intended to represent the display of a calendar/clock, rather than a point in time.  If your columns instead represent a fixed point in time, they should be stored as `TIMESTAMP` (which is automatically converted to/from UTC upon storage and retrieval according to the session timezone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [UNIX_TIMESTAMP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function insted:

```
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c.login_datetime) as `start`
FROM
  tbl_employees_login AS c ;
```

Beware that:

> The server interprets the date (or datetime) as a value in the current time zone and converts it to an internal value in UTC.