# Mysql timestamp: output UTC time instead of local server time?

Tags: mysql, timezone, timestamp

I'm creating software where I have to present time based on user's local time. The users can come from all over the world.

From what I've been reading Mysql stores timestamps in UTC and then convert it to the server timezone.

Is there anyway I can output the timestamp in the original UTC time instead of having it being automatically convert to server's local time?

I would like to do this without having to mess around with mysql's timezone settings since my software will be used in shared hosts and I don't know If I have control over those settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12290486/110933

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<your_datetime_col>)...
```